# HttpPut file upload in Java - Overriding the TrustStrategy: Is there a "better/safer" way?

Tags: java

I understand at a basic level what this block of code in my program is achieving. However, with limited understanding of *exactly* what is going on here, it seems to me like there may be a better way to do this.

```
    // Accept ALL certificates by overriding the TrustStrategy
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        }).useProtocol("TLSv1.2").build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone clarify what's happening here - or provide an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this code block does is basically say "Any certificate presented to me for a SSL connection is acceptable".

This means that it doesn't verify *anything* about the certificate (that it's signed by a trusted authority or even for the correct name).

This effectively nullifies all security benefits that SSL provides (theoretically you'd still be safe against purely passive sniffing attacks reading what you communicate, but since a man-in-the-middle attack is now trivially possible, that protection is basically pointless as well).

The safe way to avoid this code block is to only ever communicate with certificates that you trust (usually because they are signed by a widely-accepted certificate authority).